# Option --skip-slave-start Not Working with Systemctl

Tags: mysql, services, database, replication

I just started with centos 7. I'm trying to get replication working and am attempting to start mysql without starting the slave (so that I can set the pointers as to where it's supposed to resume replication before it starts). Typically I would do:

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start --skip-slave-start
```

With centos 7, I need to use systemctl to start mysql, so I thought the equivalent command would be:

```
systemctl start mysqld.service --skip-slave-start
```

but the option "--skip-slave-start" doesn't seem to be working with systemctl. It shows the error: "systemctl: unrecognized option '--skip-slave-start'". Is there any way to get this option to work with systemctl? Is there any other easy way to start mysql without starting the slave along with it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`systemctl` is not your dæmon.  It is not even a process that *spawns* your dæmon.  It is a program that *tells the service manager process to spawn your dæmon* via Desktop Bus RPC.

So `systemctl` does not know anything about the command line arguments passed to your dæmon.

Those are in your dæmon's *service unit file*, the `mysqld.service` that you mention whose location is given by

```
systemctl status mysqld.service
```

You need to change the service's `ExecStart` setting, in particular.  Here are the different ways to do this:

1. Copy the package's `mysqld.service` to your own local `/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service` service unit file.  This has the disadvantage of not tracking updates from the package.
2. Make an `/etc/systemd/system/mysqld.service.d/skip-slave.conf` *override* file that overrides *just* `ExecStart`.  The `systemd.unit` manual page explains these.
3. Edit the package-supplied `mysqld.service` service unit file.  This is simply not the systemd way.  Administrators aren't supposed to hand-edit stuff that is supplied by packages.
4. **Follow the detailed instructions given on lines 1 to 18 of [the CentOS-supplied `mysqld.service` file](https://git.centos.org/blob/rpms!mysql55-mysql/52aa8f938cd7bf3169e8264682b5a37ad7ac81a9/SOURCES!mysqld.service)**, that explain how to employ `.include` in these circumstances.

Of course, don't forget

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, and I'm sorry for my limited knowledge of Linux!  I think it might just be easier for me to just change the my.cnf file to temporarily disable the slave before starting mysql normally.  For anyone trying to do this you might want to consider looking at the answer to this question first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011233/start-mysql-with-skip-slave-start?rq=1

Basically, add:

"[mysqld]
skip-slave-start"

to the my.cnf file, start mysql, make the necessary changes, then stop mysql, chance the my.cnf file back and start mysql again.

Thanks again!